# delphi setup - error cannot start setup  corrupt or password protected 

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, installaware

i have this error at first, when i want to install `rad studio xe2` on `windows xp sp3`. im not sure which release of radstudio i have, but the name of `iso` file is `delphicbuilder_xe2_4429_win_dl`

there is full error :

> InstallAware Wizard
>
> Cannot start setup - the setup file may be corrupt, or you may have the wrong password. If you downloaded this
>   file, please download a fresh copy. If the file is password protected,
>   check your password and try again.

im sure the `iso` file isn't corrupt and isn't password protected. because i use this `iso` file, before. but i don't know why it have error when i want to start installation.

Comment: You should open a free installation issue with [Embarcadero Tech Support](http://support.embarcadero.com). Since it's an installation issue, there's no charge and no need for a maintenance agreement, and their response time is pretty quick. There is no password needed to launch the installer, so the issue has to be with the ISO image itsef.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means the file is not complete - it may be missing as few as 1 byte. The  setup will not start if it is missing any bytes.